# Questions regarding measurability of function image

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,S)$ and $(Y,T)$ be measurable spaces $X$ and $Y$ equipped with $\sigma$ algebras $S$ and $T$ respectively. Suppose function $f: (X,S)\rightarrow (Y,T)$ is measurable. Is $f(A)$ measurable $\forall$ measurable $A\in S$? If not, what if $f$ is also continuous?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the answer is negative. Let $X,Y = \mathbb{R}$, $T=\mathscr{B}$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, with respect to metric topology, and $S = 2^{\mathbb{R}}$. Consider $f(x) = x$. This function is measurable, while
$$
f(\mathcal{N}) = \mathcal{N}\notin \mathscr{B}
$$
for a non-Borel $\mathcal{N}$ (we know that there are non-Borel sets).

Comment: Nice example. However, I have now added the missed condition of measurability of $A\in X$. Please review my question now. Thank you.

Comment: Does that mean a measurable function will have every pre-image of a measurable set measurable, but not all measurable sets are mapped to a measurable set???